# Why does OS X prevent access to a folder if it ends with the word ".service"?

Tags: macos, sharing, vmware

I am sharing a win 7 folder and trying to access it from Osx.

Everything works but if the folder is named something ending with the words ".service" the folder is not accessible any more, the icon is changed and if I try to access it I get the message below.

If I remove the word "service" the folder is accessible again.

The machine is hosted inside a VmWare Fusion machine but I don't think this could be a problem, maybe something related to osx-bsd naming for services.

As I am working on folders where I can't change the names is there a way to prevent this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If Finder thinks it is a bundle, maybe you can right-click on it and "Show Package Contents"...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything you can do to prevent it.

OSX has decided, for whatever reason, that it's a service bundle (something intended to show up in the Services menu).  I'd consider filing a [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com/) about it, but have no idea how likely it would be that Apple would do anything about it.  (Were it my call, I would have done something like requiring a bundle to have a valid `Info.plist` and treat it as a normal directory otherwise.)

Comment: Thanks, you gave GEdgar the right direction, if I could put two correct answer...

Comment: Agreed, nothing practical you can do about it. In OS X several folder extensions are reserved (other examples: .app, .dvdmedia, .pkg) A Service is a kind of application bundle (see the "Finder > Services" menu for example) so OS X will treat folders with this extension as packages.